# Telegram API Base URL

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, base-url

I am new in Telegram API and I am eagerly wanted to know that, how actually it is working and How can I get the base URL to access the methods of the Telegram API.
For example I want to know how can I call the below Method in API (Windows Phone)
Link: https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.checkPhone

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The telegram.org API is unlike any other API I have worked with and requires nearly complete *mtproto* protocol implementation before you can communicate with the server, at all. This makes a typical "Hello World" type of beginners program nearly 1000 lines long.

Here is a good explanation of the protocol, at least to get the process started: https://www.incibe.es/extfrontinteco/img/File/intecocert/EstudiosInformes/INT_Telegram_EN.pdf

The above article is about defeating the telegram transport protocol (mtproto) so goes into depth about how it works, which is useful. Plus, there is a sequence diagram of authorization key creation (very helpful!).

Once you have an authorization key (from the instructions in the link above) you can send methods, like `auth.checkPhone`, to the server. Some methods will require you to login with the `auth.signIn` method successfully before they can be processed.

Good luck! It is a journey.